# Changing the content of a dropdown menu from a dropdown menu select

Tags: php, html

I have some dropdown menus. If I select one of them I want to change the other's content with something that is reliable with what i selected. How can I do that ? With html and php.

For example I have one table

```
Year   with  id_year  and  year          
Stuff  with  id_stuf  and  stuff
```

If I select an year in the first dropdown menu , in the other drodown menu will show only the stuff from that year .

This is my content with the dropdown menus

```
<div class="view">
    <form name="tabel" method="post" action="insertexamen.php">

    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td><input type="date" name="data" value="data" required="required"/><br></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>An</td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                        $sql_year="SELECT * FROM an";
                        $rez_year = mysqli_query($link,$sql_year);
                        echo "<select name=\"year\" >";
                            while($year=mysqli_fetch_array($rez_year))
                            {
                                echo "<option value=\"".$year['id_an']."\">".$year['grupa']."</option>";
                            }
                        echo "</select>";
                    ?><br>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Materie</td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                        $sql_mat="SELECT * FROM materii";
                        $rez_mat = mysqli_query($link,$sql_mat);
                        echo "<select name=\"mat\" >";
                        while($mat=mysqli_fetch_array($rez_mat))
                        {
                            echo "<option value=\"".$mat['id_mat']."\">".$mat['numemat']."</option>";
                        }
                            echo "</select>";
                    ?><br>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Profesor</td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                        $sql_proff="SELECT * FROM profesor";
                        $rez_proff = mysqli_query($link,$sql_proff);

                        echo "<select name=\"proff\" >";
                        while($proff=mysqli_fetch_array($rez_proff))
                        {
                            echo "<option value=\"".$proff['id_prof']."\">".$proff['numep']." ".$proff['prenumep']."</option>";
                        }
                            echo "</select>";
                    ?><br>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Asistent</td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                        $sql_profff="SELECT * FROM profesor";
                        $rez_profff = mysqli_query($link,$sql_profff);

                        echo "<select name=\"profff\" >";
                        while($profff=mysqli_fetch_array($rez_profff))
                        {
                            echo "<option value=\"".$profff['id_prof']."\">".$profff['numep']." ".$profff['prenumep']."</option>";
                        }
                            echo "</select>";
                    ?><br>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Sala</td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                        $sql_room="SELECT * FROM sala";
                        $rez_room= mysqli_query($link,$sql_room);

                        echo "<select name=\"room\" >";
                        while($room=mysqli_fetch_array($rez_room))
                        {
                            echo "<option value=\"".$room['id_s']."\">".$room['salaa']."</option>";
                        }
                            echo "</select>";
                    ?><br>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tip</td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                        $sql_type="SELECT * FROM examen";
                        $rez_type= mysqli_query($link,$sql_type);

                        echo "<select name=\"type\" >";
                        while($type=mysqli_fetch_array($rez_type))
                        {
                        echo "<option value=\"".$type['id_tip']."\">".$type['tip']."</option>";
                        }
                        echo "</select>";
                    ?><br>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Trimite"/></td>
                <td><input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset"/></td>
            </tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: I would recommend using JavaScript rather than PHP/HTML for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I know is more simple, but I have to make a project and we have to do it without JavaScript

Comment: You would probably have to `$_POST` the data back to the server or store it in some global variable `$_SESSION` that the server can use to re-generate the HTML file with the appropriate dropdown menu content. If you have some snippit of code you can show us, I may be able to give you a better suggestion using only PHP/HTML.

Comment: Well, you'll still need to use javascript if you want to change it without doing a form submit.  Or else every dropdown select will have to be submitted to the server.  PHP is a server side language and has no awareness of what's happening on the web browser screen. 

About the least javascripty way to do this would be AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like that:

```
<html>
<title>dropdownlist</title>
<head>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" >
function choix(formulaire)
{
var j;
var i = form1.boite1.selectedIndex;
if (i == 0)
for(j = 1; j <3; j++)
form1.boite2.options[j].text="";


else{
switch (i){
case 1 : var text = new Array( "London","Manchester","Birmingham");
break;
case 2 : var text = new Array("Paris","Marseille","Lyon");
break;

case 3 : var text = new Array("Berlin","Munich","Francfort");
break;
}

for(j = 0; j<3; j++)
form1.boite2.options[j+1].text=text[j];
}
form1.boite2.selectedIndex=0;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1">
<select name="boite1" onChange="choix(this.form)">
<option selected>country</option>
<option>England</option>
<option>France</option>
<option>Germany</option>

</select>

<select name="boite2">
<option selected>cities</option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
</form>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

if you want absolutely to do it using only html and php you will need to use some ajax because php is serverside and html is slient side. so for what you asy I would recommend the code above